# What resource types are supported by MusicKIt addToLibrary function?

Tags: apple-musickit, apple-musickit-js

My code for adding songs to user's music library looks like this:

```js
let kit = MusicKit.getInstance();
kit.authorize()
    .then(() => {
        kit.addToLibrary('1234567', 'SONGS');
    });
```

Do you know what other types, besides SONGS, are supported? Apple's [documentation of `addToLibrary` function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs/musickit/api/3001435-addtolibrary) is not very informative.

[image: Apple's documentation of addToLibrary function]